# Accessing keys and objects through python Boto and AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I read: https://ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/s3/python/

However I am looking for a way to access AWS S3 without only part of the key.

So I may have a key like this:

> myplace/yourplace/ourplace/size/color

I may have the size and color, how can I get only the keys that match this?

Do I need to do something like:

```
TheDesiredKeys
For k in all keys
     if key.split("/")[4] == desiredSize && key.split("/")[5] == desiredColor
         TheDesiredKeys.append(k)
```

Then go fetch all of the objects at those locations? I was under the impression that there was an easier way?

Also I tried:

```
 bucket.list()
```

But in all the examples it was like:

```
 b - bucket.list()
 for key in b:
      doSomething
```

However I was hoping to just get all of the keys in an object. However when I look at bucket.list() in debugger I don't see all the keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## AWS S3 keys are indexed in lexical order

It is rather easy to find a key using prefix.

But for suffix, or whatever is not really prefix, you have to loop over all the keys.

## How to do it for prefix

[boto spec](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.get_all_keys) for `bucket.get_all_keys` offers parameter `prefix`

```
>>> import boto
>>> con = boto.connect_s3()
>>> bucket_name="bucketname"
>>> bucket=con.get_bucket(bucket_name)
>>> keys = bucket.get_all_keys(prefix="region/cz/")
>>> for key in keys:
...     print key.name
...
region/cz/Prague.gif
region/cz/Ostrava.gif
```

Note: `boto.connect_s3()` assumes, you have configured system, I use `BOTO_CONFIG` environmental variable for this, but you can also specify credentials directly in this call.